# The session is unavailable because no secret key was set Flask App factory

Tags: python, session, flask, secret-key

I'm having trouble logging in my user when i try to set up an app with app factory. The app configures from a config file and when I use a print statement before create_app() it actually shows me the secret key. However when i run the app and enter the username in the login screen I get a runtime error:

> RuntimeError: The session is unavailable because no secret key was set.  Set the secret_key on the application to something unique and secret.

Could anyone point me in the right direction? I cant seem to get my head around it.

app/__init__.py

```
 from flask import Flask
    from flask_session import Session
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

    db = SQLAlchemy()


    def create_app():

        app = Flask(__name__)

        db.init_app(app)
        app.config.from_object('config.Config')

        with app.app_context():

            from .auth import auth_routes

            app.register_blueprint(auth_routes.auth_routes)

            db.create_all()

        return app
```

.env

```
SESSION_TYPE = filesystem
SECRET_KEY = verysecretkey
```

config.py

```
from os import environ


class Config:

    SESSION_TYPE = environ.get('SESSION_TYPE')
    SECRET_KEY = environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
```

Answer (score 0):

Conveying settings from `.env` into a Flask instance has two requirements: First, `python-dotenv` needs to be installed. Second, you need to be starting your app using either the `flask` command or by some path that invokes `app.run()`.

I've found it safer to be explicit in my configs, by doing

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

class Config:
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('APP_SECRET_KEY')
    ...
```

This avoids confusion when deploying under `uwsgi` et al.